# Graphics in GitHub commit messages

Tags: github, git-commit

How to add graphics/image in git commit messages (pushed to Github)?

Comment: Here is an example; http://bit.ly/ccUUKK

Comment: Another example; http://bit.ly/FOkRIX

Comment: Here is an [emerging standard of software development-related emojis in commit messages](https://github.com/dannyfritz/commit-message-emoji).

Answer (score 92):

Here is a list of codes to put in your commit message to get those icons:

**[Emoji cheat sheet](http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/)**

For instance, to get [this commit message](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/commit/42c60520722a80e3ac3ba91fa2a89905db8f9c05):

[image: Release 2.0.1 :gem::star2: (example commit message with emoji)]

enter `Release 2.0.1 :gem::star2:`.

If you see an icon on GitHub you want to use, hover your mouse over it, and the tooltip will tell you that icon’s code. Or copy and paste a commit message to convert icons to their codes.

That cheat sheet website is open-source – here is [its code](https://github.com/arvida/emoji-cheat-sheet.com).

**Caveats:** you can’t put an arbitrary image into a commit message – these codes work on GitHub only because GitHub implemented the emoji on that list. And of course, it is up to the Git interface you are using to display emoji or link URLs – Git’s command-line interface will probably not do either of those.

Comment: There are some [Suggested Emoji List](https://github.com/slashsBin/styleguide-git-commit-message)!

Answer (score 7):

Write emoji from your command line as: for emoji smile and books

```
     git commit -m ":smile: your message"      
     git commit -m ":books: documentation is completed"
```

Answer (score 3):

In my projects I use emojis mostly for: initial commits, new features, bug fix, documentation, and code refactoring. This is how i create them

```
git commit -m ":tada: for initial commit"
git commit -m ":sparkles: for a new feature"
git commit -m ":bug: for a bug fix"
git commit -m ":books: for documentation"
git commit -m ":hammer: for code refactoring"
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here it is a [list](https://gist.github.com/parmentf/035de27d6ed1dce0b36a) of other useful emojis that you can use

Answer (score 2):

To get an emoji in a commit message:

```
git commit -m "We did it, time to party :partying_face:"
```

[image]

---

A (incomplete) list of GitHub emojis can be found here: https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908